# Where can I find a real, reliable, iq test that someone could take multiple times?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, test, iq

I'm trying to find a real, reliable, accurate IQ test, that someone could take multiple times (so maybe has randomized questions?). It is for a study involving IQ and video games.

Comment: You could try to find as many IQ-tests there are and make your own data-base with the questions in it. Then you can randomly take a subset of questions (per category if necessary) and present them to your participants. As long as the set of questions are similar (i.e. the amount of "type-1" questions is the same in both sessions; maybe also in task-difficulty) you could compare the results. Do note that some IQ-tests are easier than others and may have a different rating. Anyways: here is a popular Dutch IQ-test: http://quiz.bnn.nl/iqtest2015/index.html . I hope google translate can help you.